# How I can get 0 index value in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

```
Array ( [0] => 18 [1] => 1 )
```

how i can get only 0 index value?. I am using this code in codeigniter. Can any one help?. Is this possible with for each loop so it access all indexes but show only zero index?

```
    foreach($m as $m)
{
    echo $m->['0'];
}
```

Comment: remove the foreach loop and write `echo $m[0];`

Comment: is this possible with foreach loop so it access all indexes but show only zero index?

Comment: you can try this `foreach($m as $key => $m)
{
    echo $key;
}`

Comment: it shows index number but i want value at index

Comment: @YousafFarooq without loop also you can get `echo reset($m);` try this

Comment: Show more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want only first index then you don't need to foreach loop
Just write:

```
echo $m[0];
```

And if you want all index of array then:

```
foreach ($m as $key => $value) {
  echo $key;
}
```

Comment: it shows index number but i want that i can access all indexes but show value of only 0 index

Comment: Value of first index: foreach ($m as $key => $value) {
          $data[$key] = $value;
        }
        print_r($data[0]);

Comment: @YousafFarooq you can use `count` variable inside the loop initially set it 0 `count = 0` inside the loop check if it is 0 then show the first index value otherwise show nothing and `count++`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print_r($m[0]);
```

or

```
foreach($m as $m)
{
    echo $m['0'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is the code to get value of index 0
//$array variable declared containing multiple values

```
$array=array('0' =>"first value",'1' =>"second value",'2' =>"third value" );
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($array); // helps in printing the value key and value
        //iterating through each values in the array
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            if($key==0) //checks if key is 0
            {
                echo $value; //prints the value in key 0
            }
        }
```